# Application reject in itunes EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)

Tags: ios, crash

Application rejected 2 times because of below issue. Can anyone help me?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001000bc0a4
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   APPNAME                             0x00000001000bc0a4 0x100020000 + 639140
1   APPNAME                             0x00000001000b5ca4 0x100020000 + 613540
2   APPNAME                             0x0000000100091554 0x100020000 + 464212
3   APPNAME                             0x00000001001d6b88 0x100020000 + 1797000
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000192815200 0x192814000 + 4608
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001928151c0 0x192814000 + 4544
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000192819d6c 0x192814000 + 23916
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000193937f2c 0x19385b000 + 905004
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000193935b18 0x19385b000 + 895768
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000193864048 0x19385b000 + 36936
10  GraphicsServices                0x00000001952ea198 0x1952de000 + 49560
11  UIKit                           0x00000001998492fc 0x1997ce000 + 504572
12  UIKit                           0x0000000199844034 0x1997ce000 + 483380
13  APPNAME                             0x0000000100091834 0x100020000 + 464948
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001928485b8 0x192844000 + 17848

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019293c16c 0x19293b000 + 4460
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019293bfdc 0x19293b000 + 4060
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000193937cec 0x19385b000 + 904428
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000193935908 0x19385b000 + 895240
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000193864048 0x19385b000 + 36936
5   Foundation                      0x0000000194375a8c 0x194369000 + 51852
6   Foundation                      0x000000019439657c 0x194369000 + 185724
7   UIKit                           0x000000019a1bea2c 0x1997ce000 + 10422828
8   Foundation                      0x000000019447347c 0x194369000 + 1090684
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192a20850 0x192a1d000 + 14416
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192a20760 0x192a1d000 + 14176
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192a1ddac 0x192a1d000 + 3500

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019293c16c 0x19293b000 + 4460
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019293bfdc 0x19293b000 + 4060
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000193937cec 0x19385b000 + 904428
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000193935908 0x19385b000 + 895240
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000193864048 0x19385b000 + 36936
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000194055fd0 0x193f87000 + 847824
6   Foundation                      0x000000019447347c 0x194369000 + 1090684
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192a20850 0x192a1d000 + 14416
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192a20760 0x192a1d000 + 14176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192a1ddac 0x192a1d000 + 3500

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019295a23c 0x19293b000 + 127548
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019393eb84 0x19385b000 + 932740
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192a20850 0x192a1d000 + 14416
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192a20760 0x192a1d000 + 14176
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192a1ddac 0x192a1d000 + 3500

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019295aa88 0x19293b000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192a1e178 0x192a1d000 + 4472
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192a1dda4 0x192a1d000 + 3492

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019295aa88 0x19293b000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192a1e178 0x192a1d000 + 4472
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192a1dda4 0x192a1d000 + 3492

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019295aa88 0x19293b000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192a1e35c 0x192a1d000 + 4956
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192a1dda4 0x192a1d000 + 3492

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019295aa88 0x19293b000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192a1e35c 0x192a1d000 + 4956
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192a1dda4 0x192a1d000 + 3492

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192a1dda0 0x192a1d000 + 3488

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192a1dda0 0x192a1d000 + 3488

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192a1dda0 0x192a1d000 + 3488

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192a1dda0 0x192a1d000 + 3488
```

Comment: Symbolicate the crash log and see exactly where the crash is happening in your code.

Comment: See this one Symbolic crash report where your app crash : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports

Comment: Here is appdelegate code , Is there any issue ?                       UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
        IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
        registerForPushNotifications(application)
        FIRApp.configure()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification,object: nil)